# Python code to correct lines that were split in 2, need to keep them in one line

Tags: python, split

I am trying to load data from pipe delimited text files into Azure data warehouse using Polybase. Some of records were split in multiple lines and I am having trouble loading that.

Format of data is as below:

```
col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7|col8
```

Actual data is as below

```
123|abc|def|ghi|jkl
|mno|pqr|stu
```

If the entire record is in one line, it's running fine. When the data is split as above in 2 lines it's failing.

I am loading the data to blob using Python. Please can some one let me know if there is a way to keep the record in 1 line only.

Comment: Why are some of them split across two lines?  Is the data quoted strings?  Perhaps it's supposed to have an embedded new line.  If not, then it would be easy to write a little "cleanup" routine to check for the number of columns and join the two lines, and THEN load it in.

Comment: @TimRoberts sometimes the lines were split across two lines, not sure why. Yes, that's what I am after - "cleanup" routine to check for the number of columns and join the two lines, and THEN load it in.  Please can you advise on how to do that.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you got first line like that:

```
col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7|col8
```

and second line like that:

```
123|abc|def|ghi|jkl |mno|pqr|stu
```

And all you want to do is keep all data in one line. So you join these lines like that using one more `|` character between them. So you got something like that:

```
col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7|col8|123|abc|def|ghi|jkl |mno|pqr|stu
```

Here's a simple python script which can be used for splitting this data into lists:

```py
a = 'col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7|col8|123|abc|def|ghi|jkl |mno|pqr|stu'

b = a.split('|')
c = []
for i in range(0, len(b), 8):
    c.append(b[i : i + 8])

print(c)
```

The output:

```
[['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7', 'col8'], ['123', 'abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl ', 'mno', 'pqr', 'stu']]
```

Then you can add this code to convert gotten data into `dict`:

```py
data = []
for i in range(1, len(c)):
    x = {}
    for j in range(len(c[0])):
        x[c[0][j]] = c[i][j]
    data.append(x)

print(data)
```

The output:

```
[{'col1': '123', 'col2': 'abc', 'col3': 'def', 'col4': 'ghi', 'col5': 'jkl ', 'col6': 'mno', 'col7': 'pqr', 'col8': 'stu'}]
```

Comment: I think you missed the point here.  The problem is that the lines are all supposed to have 8 columns, but some of the lines got split somehow, so there are 3 on one line and 5 on the next, or 6 on one line and 2 on the next.

Comment: Yeah, definitely, after rereading I gotta agree

Answer (score 0):

The following script will read a file containing mostly 8-column lines with the occasional line split across lines.  For example:

```
one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight
one|two|three
|four|five|six|seven|eight
one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight
one|two|three|four|five|six
|seven|eight
one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight
```

The idea here is that, if we get a short line, we save the parts as "leftovers" and wait for the next line.  I'm ASSUMING here that the second part of the broken line will begin with a '|'.  It's possible to eliminate that, but then you have to decide how to handle leading and trailing '|' symbols.

This writes the results to stdout.  You could write to another file, or even collect into a list of columns or a dataframe, if you want.

```
leftover = []
for line in open('data.txt').readlines():
    line = line.strip()
    if line[0] == '|':
        parts = leftover + line[1:].split('|')
        leftover = []
    else:
        parts = line.split('|')
        if len(parts) < 8:
            leftover = parts
        else:
            print( '|'.join(parts) )
```